# How to split xml blob content in database into multiple files based on tag in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

How to split xml file into multiple files based on a tag in xml file using mule

```
In xml we have <EOF> data based on <EOF> we need to chunk the xml.
```

Comment: Is the tag actually `<EOF />` (a closed empty tag?) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to:

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath('//EOF')]" />
```

That would generate many messages one for each EOF tag in your XML. Depending on the structure you may need to fix the Xpath expression to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Use splitter component in Mule

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Splitter+Flow+Control+Reference